# Add additional headers to all AngularJS $http requests

Tags: angularjs, express, httprequest, sails.js, angular-http

I've been looking through the documentation on AngularJS and found this:

http://puu.sh/7BCkh.png

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

I'm told I can add a header to **every** outgoing $http request that my app does. I'm adding it like so, as per documentation:

```
app.run(function($http){

    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authentication = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'

    console.log($http.defaults.headers.common.Authentication);

});
```

Logging that `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authentication` property on the client-side confirms that it **is** being set, as such: http://puu.sh/7BCDC.png

However on the receiving end of the request (my API), if I log my entire request object, that header is nowhere to be found. Here's the contents of the "req.headers" object on my API end... http://puu.sh/7BCLT.png. No authentication header to be seen.

I'm using Sails.js (an extension of Express.JS) as my RESTful API backend and AngularJS as my frontend.

Anyone mind providing some insight as to what might be going on / where I'm going wrong?

Comment: And what does the Chrome/Firebug Network tab say about the requests? Do they contain the header? If the do, then the problem is not with Angular.

Comment: Good point, checking that now...

Comment: The chrome network tab shows this as my request, also missing headers: http://puu.sh/7BGBy.png -- so angular isn't attaching it to the request from some reason.

Comment: Couldb be a same-origin-policy problem. Your client site and the server are hosted on different ports. Do you set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header? Try to run chrome with `--disable-web-security` or use a network debugger like fiddler to make sure.

Comment: How would I check that? Here's a full request / response header detail from FireFox debugger: http://puu.sh/7BMnJ.png

Comment: Shouldn't be a cross-origin problem, since this is a GET request...